# Javascript form validation not working in bootstrap 5.2

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, bootstrap-5

I'm can't get my client-side form validation to work ahead of my server-side validation. I'm using bootstrap 5.2 and have followed the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/forms/validation/) by adding `needs-validation` to and `novalidate` to the form.

**Example**

On my `event_name` input (very bottom field), I'm intentionally entering a title that's >50 characters because I've set the `input max=50`. The `invalid-feeback` never flashes and the form is submitted, only to bounce back from my server-side validation.

**Question**

Why isn't the client-side validation taking?

**Form**

```
<% layout('layouts/boilerplate') %>

<div class="row">
    <h1 class="text-center">Setup</h1>
    <div class="col-xl-8 offset-xl-2">
        <form action="/events/new" method="POST" class="needs-validation" novalidate>
            <h5 class="mt-2">Activation setup</h5>
            <hr>
            <label for="event[promotion_type]">Select which of your qr codes you'll use for this event</label>
            <div class="btn-group-lg my-4 d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center" role="group"
                aria-label="Basic radio toggle button group" required>
                <% for (let q of qr) { %>
                    <input type="radio" class="btn-check" onselect="setQrName" name="event[qr_name]" value="<%= q.name %>"
                        id="<%= q.name %>" autocomplete="off">
                    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary m-2" for="<%= q.name %>">
                        <%= q.name %>
                    </label>
                    <% } %>
            </div>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                You must select a QR code
            </div>
            <small class="form-text text-muted">*Do not select a qr code that's mapped to another
                activation. Manage qr codes on the <a href="/users/<%= user.id %>/activations">activations
                    page</a>.
            </small>

            <div class="row flex-row d-flex" style="margin-top: 4em;">
                <div class="mb-2 col-6">
                    <label class=" form-label" for="event[event_start]">Start date & time*</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="datetime-local" onchange="timeCheck()" id="eventStart"
                        name="event[event_start]" required>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        Must be filled out
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="mb-2 col-6">
                    <label class="form-label" for="event[event_end]">End date & time*</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="datetime-local" onchange="timeCheck()" id="eventEnd"
                        name="event[event_end]" required>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        Must be filled out
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p id="timeValidate" style="color: red; font-style: italic;">
                    <%= %>
                </p>
            </div>

            <div class="my-3">
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label class="form-label fw-medium" for="event_name">Activation title*</label>
                    <input class="form-control" placeholder='Ex, "Win 50% off!" or "1 in 10 win a free hat!"'
                        maxlength="50" type="text" id="event[event_name]" name="event[event_name]" required>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        Must be filled out
                    </div>
                    <small class="my-2">A short title that will get people excited to participate</small>
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary"
                        onclick="update(document.getElementById('eventStart').value,document.getElementById('eventEnd').value)">Next</button>
                </div>
        </form>
        <a href="/events">Back to all events</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript validation from boilerplate.ejs**

```
        <script>
            (function () {
                'use strict'

                // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
                var forms = document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation')

                // Loop over them and prevent submission
                Array.prototype.slice.call(forms)
                    .forEach(function (form) {
                        form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
                            if (!form.checkValidity()) {
                                event.preventDefault()
                                event.stopPropagation()
                            }

                            form.classList.add('was-validated')
                        }, false)
                    })
            })()

        </script>
```

**Callout**

As called out by @carolskelly in the comments, the `required` validation is still working so I can't submit a form where the inputs are blank.

Comment: `max` is typically used for a numeric type; did you mean `maxlength`?

Comment: Are the `required` fields catching validation errors?

Comment: @mykaf shoot, you're right. I updated the form but am still running into the same issue (also updated the code in the question)

Comment: @CarolSkelly good question... yes, the "required" validation is still working. If I try to submit the form with the fields as blank, I see client-side validation "Must be filled out" which blocks the form submission

Comment: I'm not familiar with the bootstrap validation, but it seems to require JS; can you include your JS validation code? Additionally, the `maxlength` attribute should limit your text as you type, but probably not if you paste text in.

Comment: well, if require is working, what specifically is *not* working? `maxlength` isn't a good example since it simply prevents the user from enterting more chars while typing

Comment: @mykaf added my javascript validation script to the question above and I was pasting the title. When I type it cuts me off at 50 chars. I believe this should resolve the issue, thank you!

Comment: For what it's worth, you can call `forEach()` directly on `document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation')`; no need for `Array.prototype.slice.call(forms).forEach(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/forms/validation/) for Bootstrap 5.2 Validation:

> We are aware that currently the client-side custom validation styles and tooltips are not accessible, since they are not exposed to assistive technologies. While we work on a solution, we’d recommend either using the server-side option or the default browser validation method.

Could this be the cause of the problem that you are experiencing?